# Calculate area by using double integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Area $D$ confined by lines:

$x=\sqrt{4-{y}^{2}},\: y=\sqrt{3x}, \: x\geq 0$

Need to calculate $I = \iint\limits_D \, dx\,dy$

My steps:

1. Draw $D$:

[image]

2. Set boundaries:

$I = {I}_{1} + {I}_{2}$

${I}_{2} = \frac{1}{4}\left(\pi {r}^{2} \right)=\pi$

${I}_{1} =  \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} dy \int_{\frac{1}{3}{y}^{2}}^{\sqrt{4-{y}^{2}}}dx = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{4-{y}^{2}}-\frac{1}{3}{y}^{2} \: dy = \left[2 \arcsin\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2}\sqrt{4-{y}^{2}}  \right]_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{{y}^{3}}{3} \right]_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}+\frac{2\pi }{3}$

So $I = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}+\frac{2\pi }{3} + \pi = \frac{5\pi }{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$

I have check ${I}_{1}$ via [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20%5Bsqrt%284-x%5E2%29-x%5E2%2F3%2C%20x%2C%200%2C%203%5E0.5%5D).

**But answer should be** $\frac{2\pi - \sqrt{3}}{6}$

Comment: You answer is correct for your area but you have shaded the wrong area.

Comment: @IanMiller Can you help me draw D? I still can not understand where is my mistake.

Comment: Why G2 ? indeed a constraint is missing in definition of D. can y be negative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selected the wrong area. You want the bit bound by all 3 lines mentioned.

You can get that by doing $2\pi$ take away your answer. Or recalculate the easier integral.

[image]

Comment: ok, here there is really a confinment by the 3 curves :-) (I would say it was bad not to define D with inequalities).

Comment: Thx. But I still have wrong answer...

Comment: Agree the use of the inequality is confusing.

Comment: $2\pi$ minus your original answer gave me: $\frac{2\pi-\sqrt{3}}{6}$ which I thought was what you were after.

Comment: @IanMiller Damn, in book there are no brackets and answer written in 2 lines. It confused me :) My answer is $\frac{2\pi -\sqrt{3}}{6}$. Suppose, it is right.